# login for many users using one username and password

Tags: php, authentication

I am new to php and as such am having a little with my Google searches (good / bad code).

I want to create a secure area that will allow 20-30 people read / write access to a (most probably mySQL) database, with the ability for all of them to be logged in at the same time.

Is there a simple and secure approach to this?

Comment: I should think there are a lot of examples out there - try searching for "PHP MySQL login" and similar variations.

Comment: @halfer It's not that there I can't find things, but that as I am new to php I have little knowledge of good / bad practice. I have often found Stackoverflow a good starting point for being show a 'good direction'.

Comment: A other good solution is buy the book __Head First Legs PHP & Mysql__ and read it.

Comment: @wumm - bit sarky aren't we, but that you for the book title.

Comment: Indeed, but - as you've discovered here - questions without evidence  of prior effort tend to get downvoted. Readers like to see code first, I've found - hence the popularly asked question, "what have you tried"?

Comment: Additional useful search terms (not PHP specific): roles, salting, hashing.

Comment: @halfer, To be honest I find it a bit hit and miss. Sometimes people are super helpful, sometimes not. (I think it varies from language to language).

Comment: The problem with your question is that it is very broad. You are basically asking for a tutorial (at least it sounds like it) and that's not what SO is for.

Comment: @FelixKling - yeah, my bad. Not after (nor expecting) a tutorial at all. Merely hoped to that someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

make a file (I will name it secure.php for example)

secure.php:

```
<?php
  $username = 'username';
  $password = 'password';

  if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ||
    ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secure Area"');
    exit('You are not authorized'); 
  }
?>
```

Then include secure.php in the file(s) which should be secure(with the username and the password):

```
include('secure.php');
```

This example uses the HTTP authentication. What the user type into the dialog we get in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`

Answer (score 0):

You can have secure, or you can have simple; asking for both probably is wishful thinking unless you're already experienced in the underlying technology (which is redefining "simple").

Given where you're starting from, you can either start with some [basic tutorials](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php.htm) and a steep learning curve, or (a much better solution) just download/install some off-the-shelf existing open source app that achieves whatever it is you want to do... That won't necessarily be secure, but it's certainly simpler & very likely more secure than starting from scratch (esp. if you're new to the toolset).